# Is There A Way To Initialize Structure Variables Prior To Defining Them? C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, variables, struct

Under this is my current code, I have a structure called 'SCENE' which holds information I can use to change the value of some Win32 windows in a different file, The struct is somewhat simple:

```
struct SCENE
{
    LPCWSTR SceneButtonOneText;                // Text For Button One
    SCENE* SceneButtonOneDestination;          // Next Scene To Go To When Button One Is Pressed
    LPCWSTR SceneButtonTwoText;                // Text For Button Two
    SCENE* SceneButtonTwoDestination;          // Next Scene To Go To When Button Two Is Pressed
    LPCWSTR SceneButtonThreeText;              // Text For Button Three
    SCENE* SceneButtonThreeDestination;        // Next Scene To Go To When Button Three Is Pressed
    LPCWSTR SceneButtonFourText;               // Text For Button Four
    SCENE* SceneButtonFourDestination;         // Next Scene To Go To When Button Four Is Pressed
    LPCWSTR SceneTextBoxContent;               // Text To Be Displayed Inside Of Window
    LPCSTR SceneImgDrc;                        // Directory For An BITMAP To Be Displayed Inside A Window
};
```

As Seen above once a button is pressed it'll go to the next scene, although an issues arises when going to a previous scene, due to the fact that the variable for the scene has not yet been initialised, I'm not sure what to do here, I tried doing some sort of 'Structure Prototyping' like you can do with functions although that didnt work, I tried writing

```
SCENE Scene4;
SCENE Scene5;
SCENE Scene6;
SCENE Scene6;
```

Above the full code to see if it could initialised, although my compiler threw an error about structure redefinition,
Full Code Below:

```
// Scenes . hpp

// Includes

#include <Windows.h>

// Structures

struct SCENE
{
    LPCWSTR SceneButtonOneText;
    SCENE* SceneButtonOneDestination;
    LPCWSTR SceneButtonTwoText;
    SCENE* SceneButtonTwoDestination;
    LPCWSTR SceneButtonThreeText;
    SCENE* SceneButtonThreeDestination;
    LPCWSTR SceneButtonFourText;
    SCENE* SceneButtonFourDestination;
    LPCWSTR SceneTextBoxContent;
    LPCSTR SceneImgDrc;
};

// Prototypes



// Scenes

SCENE Scene7 = SCENE // Front Yard
{
    L"Search Bedroom",
    &Scene7,
    L"Search Kitchen",
    &Scene4,
    L"Search Living Room",
    &Scene5,
    L"Search Backyard",
    &Scene6,
    L"",
    "./Images/TatesHouseWTate.bmp"
};
SCENE Scene6 = SCENE // Backyard
{
    L"Search Bedroom",
    &Scene6,
    L"Search Kitchen",
    &Scene4,
    L"Search Living Room",
    &Scene5,
    L"Search Front Yard",
    &Scene7,
    L"",
    "./Images/TatesBackyardWTate.bmp"
};
SCENE Scene5 = SCENE // Living Room
{
    L"Search Bedroom",
    &Scene5,
    L"Search Kitchen",
    &Scene4,
    L"Search Backyard",
    &Scene6,
    L"Search Front Yard",
    &Scene7,
    L"",
    "./Images/TatesLivingRoomWTate.bmp"
};
SCENE Scene4 = SCENE // Kitchen
{
    L"Search Bedroom",
    &Scene4,
    L"Search Living Room",
    &Scene5,
    L"Search Backyard",
    &Scene6,
    L"Search Front Yard",
    &Scene7,
    L"",
    "./Images/TatesKitchenWTate.bmp"
};
SCENE Scene3 = SCENE // Waking Up
{
    L"Search Kitchen",
    &Scene4,
    L"Search Living Room",
    &Scene5,
    L"Search Backyard",
    &Scene6,
    L"Search Front Yard",
    &Scene7,
    L"",
    "./Images/TatesBedroomWTate.bmp"
};
SCENE Scene2 = SCENE // Ceiling
{
    L"Get Up",
    & Scene3,
    L"",
    & Scene2,
    L"",
    & Scene2,
    L"",
    & Scene2,
    L"",
    "./Images/CeilingFan.bmp"
};
SCENE Scene1 = SCENE // Black
{
    L"Open Eyes",
    & Scene2,
    L"",
    & Scene1,
    L"",
    & Scene1,
    L"",
    & Scene1,
    L"",
    "./Images/Black.bmp"
};
SCENE Scene0 = SCENE // Start
{
    L"",
    & Scene0,
    L"Play",
    & Scene1,
    L"Exit",
    & Scene0,
    L"",
    & Scene0,
    L"Text",
    "./Images/Image.bmp"
};
```

All help is greatly appreciated! thanks!

Comment: You can try a *forward declare*, which looks like `extern SCENE Scene4;`

Comment: Perfect Thanks Mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks 'Elijay', Didn't realise it was that easy,

```
extern SCENE Scene4;
```

Worked perfectly!

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.